# LightDM: How can I trigger a bash command everytime someone fail to login?

Tags: bash, login, security, lightdm

I'd like to take and save a picture from the webcam, every time someone tries to login into the system and fails. I know I can do that with:

```
mplayer -vo png -frames 1 tv://
```

The question is: How can I trigger this command when someone fails to login w/ LightDM?

Comment: There are many ways. One way is to monitor the `/var/log/auth.log` file. Something like `tail -1 /var/log/auth.log | grep failure`

Comment: Although lightdm does have a number of [system hooks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Adding_System_Hooks) I'm not sure if any of them is suitable for this. I think the preferred approach is to use PAM. See for example [Taking a picture with a laptop webcam after entering an incorrect password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289476/taking-a-picture-with-a-laptop-webcam-after-entering-an-incorrect-password)

Comment: Which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 2):

## Explanation

One way is to make use of the Authorization Log.

> **Authorization Log**
>
> The Authorization Log tracks usage of authorization systems, the
>   mechanisms for authorizing users which prompt for user passwords, such
>   as the Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM) system, the sudo command,
>   remote logins to sshd and so on. The Authorization Log file may be
>   accessed at `/var/log/auth.log`. This log is useful for learning about
>   user logins and usage of the sudo command.
>
> [More here on LinuxLogFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles)

On a failed login attempt, a record will be appended to the `/var/log/auth.log` file and the last line will contain something like:

```
pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure;
```

If you constantly monitor the file for modification and check if the last line contains the keyword **failure** with for example `grep failure` then you know a failed login attempt has just occurred and you can run whatever command you want based on this action.

---

## Solution

You can monitor the last line of the `/var/log/auth.log` file with a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
       sleep 1


        if (( $(tail -1 /var/log/auth.log | grep failure | wc -l) == 1))

        then

                echo "failed login"

                # Your command here

        fi

done
```

Or even better, you can install `inotify-tools` and use `inotifywait` to monitor the file instead of the `sleep 1` and the script will be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while inotifywait -q -e modify /var/log/auth.log >/dev/null

do

        if (( $(tail -1 /var/log/auth.log | grep failure | wc -l) == 1))

        then

                echo "failed login"

                # Your command here

        fi


done
```

`inotify-tools` can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo apt install inotify-tools
```

---

## Implementation

To run this solution as a system service, please follow these steps:

- Copy and paste the script code above ( *without `echo "failed login"` as I added this line for debugging purposes only* ) into a file in your home directory and name it `TakePicture.sh` and save the file.
- Make the shell script file **executable** by running the following command in the terminal:

```
chmod +x ~/TakePicture.sh
```

- Create and edit a custom systemd service to run the shell script at boot by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/TakePicture.service
```

- Copy and paste the following code into the editor, replace `USERNAME` with **your username** and save it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> :

```
[Unit]
Description=Take Picture

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/USERNAME/TakePicture.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- Start the service by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl start TakePicture
```

- Enable the service by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl enable TakePicture
```

---

**Notice**:

The authorization Log will contain all sorts of failed logins or authentications ( ie. GDM, SSH, terminal user authentication, sudo, ... etc. ).

If your aim is just to activate the script when an actual physical login happens ( ie. someone is sitting infront of your computer, using your keyboard and looking at your screen ), then you need to change the above if statement to be like this:

```
if (( $(tail -1 /var/log/auth.log | grep gdm | grep failure | wc -l) == 1))
```

if **GDM** is your login manager. This way the script will only be triggered if an actual failed physical login happens.

Best of luck