# Startup Auto-Execution Bash Script

Tags: bash, scripts, startup

First post here. Please be gentle

There's a way to execute a bash command during the startup of Linux operating system?
I could always put the script in `/usr/local/bin` open the terminal and recall it, but is a little bit annoying.

**EDIT1** as suggested by **steeldriver**: The script has to enter in a root folder and change 2 values of charge thresold contained in a text file. For each start-up I'd like to be sure that the battery level wouldn't go over the 80%.

So in order to do that the script would execute a:

- `cd` command
- `sed -i 's/0 100/0 80/g'`

all of this, I think, has to be in sudo mode

**EDIT2**: as asked by **K7AAY** user:

Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS version, I'm not using any virtualization.

---

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Yes there is - but the right way to do it depends on what the command does and what you mean by "startup of Linux operating system" - please [edit] you question with details.

Comment: You can create a systemd service to run your shell script at boot. An example is implemented in the last part of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1213714/968501)

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `crontab -e`

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/yourscript
```

You could also copy your `*.desktop` applications into `~/.config/autostart/` or scripts into `~/.config/autostart-scripts/` directory. But, instead of copying, use `ln -s pathtoscript ~/.config/autostart-scripts/`

You could also use the next GUI for it if you use KDE Plasma:

[image]

Or, for Unity:

[image]