# How to make a script execute on failed physical login?

Tags: bash, ssh, login, authentication, pam

So I have setup the PAM for my laptop in such way that if there is a failed login attempt, a bash script is executed by which webcam takes a shot and on three consecutive failed login attempts a siren goes on and if a hotkey that I have set is not pressed within three minutes the system goes to a shutdown.
You can find more details [here](https://github.com/iamhrishikeshpadhye/Shell-it-with-ease/tree/master/lockdown) 
Now the problem is, this is setup with the `common-auth` of the `pam.d` so it works for all kinds of authentications including physical logins, superuser and SSH as well.
 So if a kid is trying SSH logins on my system, the script will make the webcam take my shots and further on three failed attempts from the kid over the wire, will make an alarm go on on my system and later cause a shutdown. This is totally unintended function of my authentication setup.
My question is, is there any way I can restrict the `common-auth` for physical logins only? 
I have found we can do same task for SSH explicitly with the help of `sshd` of `pam.d`. But can we do it for physical logins?

Comment: You can follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1213714/968501) and change the if statement in it to be like this `if (( $(tail -1 /var/log/auth.log | grep gdm | grep failure | wc -l) == 1))` if GDM is your login manager. This way the script will only be triggered if an actual failed physical login happens. Best of luck