# How to trigger a notification for any console login?

Tags: command-line, login, pam

I'm trying to find a way to trigger a notification script when anyone logs in via a console (so not ssh).

There are many examples around that use PAM/pam_exec (for SSH) and these work fine, but after many searches I can't find the equivalent way to trigger for any console based connection (literally just logging on at the screen prompt/VMS panel).

The notification script works fine, its just finding how to trigger it for all console connections.

Maybe I'm missing the correct keywords when searching?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1213714 … You need to grep for success instead with your desired authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using the wrong file under `/etc/pam.d/` (is it `common-auth`?) ... So, if that is the case, you need to undo your changes to that file and then use the right one for your purpose i.e. `login` in this case which contains the configuration for the login service ... See [`man pam.d`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/pam.d.5.html) for more information.

That should be done by editing the file `/etc/pam.d/login` and appending after this part:

```sh
# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth
```

... this line:

```sh
auth    [default=ignore]                pam_exec.so seteuid /path/to/your/script
```

.. So, it'll look like so:

```sh
# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth
auth    [default=ignore]                pam_exec.so seteuid /path/to/your/script
```

That said, that method is risky as it requires great care or otherwise you might find yourself locked out unable to login to that system using that authentication mechanism and it might not work if you don't stack PAM modules the right way ... It's, also, not suitable for long running scripts as they will delay the authentication/login process and it's not suitable for running scripts that will rely on services normally available after user login as those services might not start/exist until all PAM processing has completed ... Therefore, in those cases, you might want to [consider other methods](https://askubuntu.com/a/1213714).

Comment: Thanks this is excellent, really clearly explained.  
I was using /etc/pam.d/sshd, and didn't realise there was one for login.  Had added:
session optional pam_exec.so /opt/my_scripts/login_notification.sh

Have started assembling a script that monitors logs like in the "consider other methods" because if something went wrong with the externally provided push notification service it interfaces into, I wouldn't want to muck up the console connections.  Thanks so much for the assistance, am learning loads :-D

Comment: @BinChicken You are welcome and I'm glad I could help … I, however, was under the impression that you script triggers on all kinds of authentication including SSH, hence my guess at `common-auth`. But now, after you mentioned `sshd`, I understand that your script **only** triggered on SSH  … You don’t want both files anyway. What you want is the `login` file still and I understand you know that now … I also agree that such script is better run outside PAM  … PAM is more suitable for simple basic controlled commands/scripts IMO.

Comment: Thanks @Raffa in the end I used your /etc/pam.d/login trigger because the log scanning was missing some lines. Works on server but PAM trigger for login not firing when used on Ubuntu desktop. Is that expected? Thx!

Comment: @BinChicken Yes, that is expected as desktop user logins are handled by another service which is the graphical login manager/greeter with different PAM configuration files that are called instead e.g. `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password` ... Have a look at all files under `/etc/pam.d/` and read the comments in each one describing its function ... Usually, each authentication service has its own PAM configuration file and some are common to many services like `common-auth` or a fail-safe measure like `other` for example.

Comment: Thanks @Raffa that was such a help and put me on the right track, it's all working now - used 3xPAM modules for ssh/text_console/gui_console all triggering a script that shouldn't block/lock out anything (has max time limit for curl statement (to send push message notification), plus "or true" option on it ( || true) so it should never fail).  So happy now, every type of logon and phone/watch buzz :-D